# Remove attribute from entity

Tags: magento-1.9, entity-manager

I added attributes in this way without problems:

```
$this->startSetup();
$installer = new Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Setup('core_setup');
$entities = array(
    'quote_item',
);
$options = array(
    'type'     => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_DECIMAL,
    'visible'  => true,
    'required' => false
);
foreach ($entities as $entity) {
    $installer->addAttribute($entity, 'packing', $options);
}
$installer->endSetup();
$this->endSetup();
```

But when I try to remove the attributes it gives me error: WRONG Entity ID:

```
$this->startSetup();
$installer = new Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Setup('core_setup');
$entities = array(
    'quote_item',
);
foreach ($entities as $entity) {
    $installer->removeAttribute($entity, 'packing');
}
$installer->endSetup();
$this->endSetup();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
$attribute = 'packing'; 
$setup->removeAttribute('quote_item', $attribute);
$setup->endSetup();
```

Comment: This example is the same as mine, only that I do a cycle. Does not work.
M1.9.3.3

#0 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Setup.php(194): Mage::exception('Mage_Eav', 'Wrong entity ID')
#1 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Setup.php(881): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup->getEntityTypeId('quote_item')
#2 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Setup.php(987): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup->getAttribute('quote_item', 'packing')
#3 /var/www/html/test.php(8): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup->removeAttribute('quote_item', 'packing')